# Angularjs - add a service to a self invoking function

Tags: angularjs

Im reworking my app to load the page after the data is loaded. I have the data, but i need to get it to my other two controllers. I have a self provoking function inside my main app.js. I also have a service in there.

I am unable to figure out how to reference the service, in the function, so i can add the data there. Therefore, be accessible from my other controllers.

Here is the app.js with the function i need to reference the service and the service itself. I will post the full code.

```
var app = angular.module('UtilityApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngDialog', 'uiSwitch', 'ui.select', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(

    [ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login-page.html',
            controller : 'LoginController'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            resolve:{
                'LoginServiceData':function(LoginService){
                    return LoginService.promise;
                }},
            templateUrl: 'templates/Homepage.html'
        });

    }]);
```

```
(function($scope, UserService) {

var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $http = initInjector.get('$http');


    $http.get('rest/userdata/').
    success(function (data) {

       //  angular.module('metadata', []).constant('userdata', data);
        // UserDataService.setUserData(data);
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['UtilityApp']);

        });

    }).
    error(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });

setInterval(function(){
    $scope.getMetaData();
}, 300000);

})();
```

Hopefully, theres a way to use the UserService in the function. I added it as a parameter but it cant find setUserData.

**EDIT**
I need a way to get the data from the $http.get to the other controllers I have not shown in different js files

Comment: How do you get `$scope` into the function? I don't see any arguments passed to it. Either way, you should be able to inject your custom service just like you inject `$http`

Comment: In the AngularJS world, all post-bootstrap code should be in a registered Angular injectable. You shouldn't have any IIFE running out in the global space. Your `$http.get()` should be in a service. If you need to load that data as soon as the app loads, call that service from a `.run()` block.

Comment: I need a way to get the data from the  $http.get to the other controllers I have not shown in different js files

Comment: $scope  isnt injected. I have it there but its not working.

Comment: Ok, i will try injecting it

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are [deprecated and removed from V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339). That `makePromise` function is unnecessary. Simply return the promise created by the `$http.get` service.

Comment: Im trying to get UserDataService only

Comment: I guess i am unsure what to do

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The OP wants get data from an `$http.get` promise to another service. Instead of asking how to do that the OP is asking about self-invoking functions and injectors.

Comment: You are correct, but i think i refined my problem down. My apologies.

Comment: The reason why i asked the way i did because doing so out of a self-invoking functions seems impossible.

Comment: I think you probably could use the `$injector` to get the `UserDataService` outside of the scope of your AngularJS application but _you really should not_. The `$injector` you're currently getting is only accessing the 'ng' module. If you add your app module there, you should be able to get the services you registered.

Comment: How would i inject the module? I tried  var initInjectorModule = angular.injector(['mappingUtilityApp']); but i get a host of errors. like ngdialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app structure is wrong. You should not try to load data in an IIFE then bootstrap the AngularJS app. Do it all in AngularJS instead as below. There is a `myDataService` that handles loading and providing the data. There is a `.run()` block that triggers the data load as soon as the app starts. You can then disable functionality in your app as needed until the `myDataService.dataLoaded` flag is set to true.

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ngRoute]);

app.service("myDataService", function($http) {
  var service = this;
  service.data = [];

  service.dataLoaded = false;

  service.loadData = function() {
    return $http.get("/my/data/url")
      .then(function(response) {
        service.data = response.data;
        service.dataLoaded = true;
      });
  };

});

app.run(function(myDataService) {
  myDataService.loadData();
});
```

Comment: app.run  is not firing

Comment: You probably aren't bootstrapping your app anymore. Use the `ng-app` method or the manual bootstrap method.